# WPF: System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap to  System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, interop, bitmap

Is there a way to convert System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap to  System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using the code below. msg.ThumbnailSource contains System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap type of object

```
BitmapSource bmpSource = msg.ThumbnailSource as BitmapSource;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpSource));
encoder.Save(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the pixels using CopyPixels and use the code from [the Bitmap.Lock/Unlock documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.unlockbits.aspx#Y500) to pass the pixels to the Bitmap.